# Normal website body as Angular 2 Componentwithout replacing them

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I want to make my website modern with some cool features.
For this I used jQuery and self made things. But that's slow and everything I developed is easier in Angular.

So I started to implement the Angular 2 code into my normal website.
The things (app.component, main.ts, app.module) work. I have the angular functionality on my page.

That's the first try.

Now I found out that I can't use second and third components (this ones which are not in bootstrap array) not within the selector.
So the bootstrapped component is the root-element for everything I think.

The next step was to replace the whole body as a component.
For example with angular 1 it was easy: `ng-controller="app"` and finish.
I can do this with `<body>` and everything.

Now with Angular 2 I must define a template for the component. else I get this error `Uncaught Error: No template specified for component AppComponent`

So the questions are...

1. Is it possible to use the  as selector for the app so that I can use components within the app without bootstrapping them?
2. Or is there a way to use the components flexible?

The main reason is:
**I want to define components globally which must not exist on each page. So I can have a component which is called `test-component` which is only used on test.html and a `about-component` which is only used on about.html**

You understand?

Currently the problem is that I get this error: `app.js:116448EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements` and `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements`

If I define them both it works. But if one component is missing then I get this error.

Current scripts:

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1> <a (click)="test()">:)</a>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor (private http: Http) {}
    name = 'Angular';
    test() {
        alert('Yay');
        return this.http.get('/asd/aaa/test').subscribe((a) => {
            console.log('A', a);
        }, (b) => {
            console.log('B', b);
        });
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent}  from './app.component';
import {JsonpModule, HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {TestComponent} from "./test.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        TestComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent,
        // TestComponent // this shouldnt be a bootstrap because else the component MUST exist on the page!
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Component({
    selector: 'test-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1> <a (click)="test()">:)</a>`
})
export class TestComponent {
    constructor (private http: Http) {}
    name = 'Angular !!!!!!!!!!!!';
    test() {
        alert('yyyyy');
        return this.http.get('/asd/aaa/test').subscribe((a) => {
            console.log('A', a);
        }, (b) => {
            console.log('B', b);
        });
    }
}
```

As I said if I want to use the body as root element it replaces everything of the body. And this is not for my use case.

It's only a normal website. Multiple HTML (background = PHP) pages.

I could implement this `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` on each page where I need something. Then I could write a module for each page. I think this could solve the problem, too. But it's bad... Having a lot of modules...

Comment: Angular is intended to be used for single-page applications. So 'Multiple HTML' approach along with PHP is actually misleading you. You need to pick one of them.

Comment: It mostly works so why I should not do it like this way. Yes of course Angular is single page... But I only need to do have components which are not bootstrapped directly. A simple if elements.length > 0 will be enough.